# Check for nested tables via Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I tried this wanting to find if a table is nested.

```
 // Nested Tables
            Elements table = doc.getElementsByTag("table");
            table.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {
                public void head(Node node, int x) {
                    if (!(node instanceof TextNode)) {
                        System.out.println(node.childNodes());
                        if (node.childNodes().contains("<table>")) {
                            tables++;
                        }

                    }
                }

                public void tail(Node node, int x) {
                }
            });
            // Nested Tables
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int nTables = 0;
Elements tables = doc.getElementsByTag("table");
for(Element table : tables) {
    for(Element child : table.children()) {
        Elements nestedTables = child.getElementsByTag("table");
        if(!nestedTables.isEmpty()) {
            nTables++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me greatly. I was trying and failing to write complicated selectors. Your idea of looping all tables and inspecting each to find my desired one is so much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Or simple try `doc.select("table table").size()`. The selector check for a second table tag down the child tags. So it give the number of table tags with at least one child table.